# Async tasks in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a question about the working of async tasks in ansible.

Suppose, I open 2 terminals, and run `sudo apt-get update` on both. Obviously, it will not run on both due to the lock file.

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/etc/ansible$ sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Now, on ansible, I did this,

```
- name: update cache
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
  async: 1
  poll: 0

- name: update cache
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
  async: 1
  poll: 0
```

Now, the role containing these 2 consecutive tasks should never be completed as ansible cannot run 2 update tasks simultaneously.

But still it did, and did not threw any error. Why is it so ?

Comment: I see only async task execution and no results checking with `async_status`...

Comment: I didnt get u @KonstantinSuvorov . You mean to say that, none of them is completed ?

Comment: I suspect the first is successful and the second one is failed. Did you see examples at http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_async.html?

Comment: Yes, I have. What will happen if task takes 20 seconds to run but async is 10, and poll is also 10 ? Will it be completed ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you try it? add `async_status` to your playbook and fiddle with async/poll numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As you have used `poll: 0`, ie: fire-and-forget, for just 1 second, as specified in `async: 1`, your shell terminal session is active for just one second, that is after the very first second of running updating command at the remote node, it will be terminated and thus giving the second task a chance to do the same for the next 1second releasing the lock from

```
/var/lib/apt/list/lock
```

I hope this explains the scenerio :)

Comment: if you set the async time to, let's say 60, I hope it will still show you that same error saying that  the lock for apt pprocess is claimed by some other session :) @Luv33preet

Comment: You can use backticks ` and 4 leading spaces to have SO automatically highlight your code. I edited you answer, it makes your post easier to read and understand :-)